# For loop execution in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am new to python and just in the initial phase of the basics. Can someone please explain me how the for loop in the below code works? and I really don't get how number 9 is getting 3 as inner value.

Kindly tell me how the loops executes. TIA.

CODE:

```
for outer in range(2,10):
    for inner in range(2,outer):
        if not outer%inner:
            print(outer,'=',inner,'*',int(outer/inner))
            break   
    else:
        print(outer,'is prime')
```

---

```
Output:
2 is prime
3 is prime
4 = 2 * 2
5 is prime
6 = 2 * 3
7 is prime
8 = 2 * 4
9 = 3 * 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop runs multiple times for each execution of outer loop.

For value of 9 of outer loop, the inner loop executes from 2 to outer value.

Answer (score 1):

I commented your code below, It should explain what is going on.

```
# This loop loops through numbers 2-9, and assigns them to the variable 'outer'
for outer in range(2,10):
    # This loop loops through numbers 2-(outer-1), and assigns them to the variable 'inner'
    for inner in range(2,outer):
        # if outer % inner == 0, the code is executed
        if not outer%inner:
            # When this is executed for 9, it will print 9 = 3 * 3
            print(outer,'=',inner,'*',int(outer/inner))
            break   
    else:
        print(outer,'is prime')
```

Comment: first comment loops through 2-9 and assigns them to variable would be correct

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop executes multiple times for every one execution of the outer loop.

For an outer value of 9 your inner loop will execute from 2 to (outer) which is 9.